# View asset/holdings breakdown within fund

Tags: mutual-funds, yahoo-finance, fidelity, morningstar-star-rating

Is the asset allocation breakdown available for mutual funds ? For example , for the Fidelity Magellan fund (fmagx) I found following breakdowns :

Yahoo finance : https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FMAGX/holdings?p=FMAGX displays the top 10 holdings which is 31% of fund but it does not display all holdings.

Morningstar doesn't appear to provide any level of holdings breakdown : http://portfolios.morningstar.com/fund/summary?t=fmagx&region=USA&culture=en-US

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to the [SEC](https://www.sec.gov/fast-answers/answersmfinfohtm.html):

> **Shareholder Reports**
>
> A mutual fund and a closed-end fund respectively must provide
>   shareholders with annual and semi-annual reports 60 days after the end
>   of the fund’s fiscal year and 60 days after the fund’s fiscal
>   mid-year. These reports contain updated financial information, a list
>   of the fund’s portfolio securities, and other information. The
>   information in the shareholder reports will be current as of the date
>   of the particular report (that is, the last day of the fund’s fiscal
>   year for the annual report, and the last day of the fund’s fiscal
>   mid-year for the semi-annual report).
>
> **Other Reports**
>
> A mutual fund and a closed-end fund must file a Form N-Q each quarter
>   and a Form N-PX each year on the SEC’s EDGAR database, although funds
>   are not required to mail these reports to shareholders. Funds disclose
>   portfolio holdings on Form N-Q. Form N-PX identifies specific
>   proposals on which the fund has voted portfolio securities over the
>   past year and discloses how the fund voted on each. This disclosure
>   enables fund shareholders to monitor their funds’ involvement in the
>   governance activities of portfolio companies.

which means that sixty days after the end of each quarter they will tell you what they owned 60 days ago. This makes sense; why would they want to tell the world what companies they are buying and selling.

Answer (score 1):

The full holdings will be listed in the annual report of the fund, obviously the holdings would only be completely accurate as of the date of the reporting.

[This is the most recent annual report for FMAGX](http://doc.morningstar.com/latestdoc.aspx?clientid=schwab&key=84b36f1bf3830e07&cusip=316184100&investmenttype=1&documenttype=4).  I got it from my Schwab research section under "All Fund Documents" but I'm sure you can find it other ways.  When I use google to search for "fmagx annual report" [this link](http://quote.morningstar.com/fund-filing/Annual-Report/2014/3/31/t.aspx?t=FMAGX&ft=N-CSR&d=9d7dca8377ceb99b11dc518fafcbce3f) was the first result.